# Get Advanced Custom Field Group for specific taxonomy term

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to get an Advanced Custom Field Group for specific taxonomy term it's been assigned to. I've come across:

```
acf_get_field_groups();
```

Easy enough to get a group from a post ID and also from a taxonomy, but when trying to get it for a term I'm having no luck;

Tried these:

```
acf_get_field_groups(array('term_id' => '1293'));

acf_get_field_groups(array('taxonomy' => 'services','term_id' => '1293'));
```

Either this function is not capable of doing what I'm expecting it is, or I am not providing the argument format correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logic you are attempting is essentially "return all field groups that display on all posts that have term_id xyz". Which would look something like this:

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
  'numberposts' => -1,
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
      'field' => 'term_id',
      'terms' => 1, /// where term_id of term 1 is "1".
      'include_children' => false
    )
  )
));
// Get the id's from every post.
$post_ids = wp_list_pluck($posts, 'ID');
// Combine them into a comma split string
$post_ids = implode(',', $post_ids);
// Fetch our field groups.
$field_groups = acf_get_field_groups(array('post_id' => $post_ids))
```

You can also create a custom ACF filter to match it for you, this is probably the best and most efficient way:

```
add_filter('acf/location/rule_match/post_taxonomy',
    function ( $result, $rule, $screen ) {

        $value = acf_maybe_get( $screen, 'post_taxonomy' );

        // bail early if not taxonomy
        if( !$value ) return false;

        $match = ( $value == $rule['value'] );

        // Return.
        return $match;

    }
, 10, 4);
var_dump(acf_get_field_groups(array('post_taxonomy' => 'post_tag:test')));
```

Comment: You CAN assign an ACF field group to a post with a specific term when you set location to "Show field if [Post Taxonomy] [is equal to] [term]"(maybe this is an ACF PRO feature) I can easily return field groups assigned to posts even a specific post by using acf_get_field_groups(array('post_id' => $post_id); I am trying to return field groups NOT posts. I have built a solution so far was to get all field groups using acf_get_field_groups(); and then filter the results based on the location parameter returned in that object.

Comment: I didn't realise this was the case. Thank you for informing me.

With regards to the final example... it does not return posts... it returns field groups as requested. It returns all field groups that displayed on all posts that have a term. Which is exactly what you asked for.
However I will attempt to come up with a native acf_get_field_groups solution now I know that ACF actually has this support.

Comment: Sorry read your answer again there I see it returns acf group. The purpose of this for some context is that I'm building a custom rest route with acf field groups grouped my the term_id, each of my terms have a group associated with them and I need to get a group on the fly via ajax when a user enters the term in a form.

Comment: Cool I'll check it out